# Exporting and importing same package from an osgi bundle

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I have a class `org.foo.Customer` in an osgi bundle `Bundle1` and another class 
`org.foo.Subscriber` in another osgi bundle `Bundle2` in the same osgi environment. Bundle1 exports-package org.foo .

Is it possible to `import org.foo` package of `Bundle2` by `Bundle1`. Will there be any conflict during runtime as the same package is specified in export and import in the manifest file of `Bundle1` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split packages are [strongly discouraged](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1007_charters/1007_charters.html#sec8) in OSGi. If you own these bundles, you should either rename one or both packages, or join the split package into one bundle.

Bundle2 could import the split package, but then the classloader of Bundle2 would only see the classes in Bundle1, not those internally in Bundle2.

You could make one of the bundles a [fragment](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.fragmentbundles) of the other, which has the effect that they will use the same classloader. This requires changing only the manifest of the fragment bundle, and could be an option if you for some reason cannot join the bundles or change the package names.

Comment: link to the fragment page isn't available anymore. any updates about this please/

Comment: Replaced the dead 'fragment' link with a link to the OSGi specification section about fragments.